# How do I select a slicer option based on the slicer item number if my pivot table is based on a data model?

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I have this data table that updates everyday with new data and the pivot table and slicer refresh automatically through a macro. Now, I wanted to write a macro to select the newly added slicer option and deselect the previous option, while not messing with the other earlier options that are also selected (multi-select slicer). The way I was going about it was to count the number of slicer items and then pass that index number to SlicerItems(i).select = True for the desired options. But it looks like you can only pass an array to data model based pivot slicer?

Here's my code

```
n = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").SlicerCacheLevels(1).SlicerItems.Count
 
'tried this
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").SlicerItems(n).Selected = True
'also tried this format 
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").SlicerCacheLevels(1).SlicerItems(n - 3).Selected = False
```

Is there any workaround to pass the item number or any other way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Not enough info to answer. From what I can see, you should address `SlicerCache`, not `Slicer`. Also, I expect `SlicerItems(i).Selected` instead of `item(i).select`. Try to add more details in the description of your problem.

Comment: My bad. I've edited the description.